# Analytical solution to the diffusion of a step function in spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-equations, diffusion

Is there an analytical solution to the heat diffusion of a step function in spherical coordinates? This corresponds to an infinite solid homogeneous medium in which a spherical portion is initially (quickly) heated to a constant temperature higher than the rest of the medium.

Formally, the equation is:

$$\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}$$
with $T = T_0$ for $r < r_0$ and $T = 0$ else.

Comment: There most certainly is! Have a look [here](http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/~ernesto/S2006/CHT/Notes/ch03.pdf) and then update us with what you do and don't understand.

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Focusing on the case of the step function, this is still tricky. From your link, 1d (in radial direction) spherical problems can always be converted into a 1d cartesian diffusion equation with a change of variables. However, the change also deforms the initial condition (the step becomes a ramp) and I don't know if pursuing the solving could lead to an analytical solution.